# Use RAII with factory taking as input a reference to pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, raii

I have a function which construct an object, and it takes as input a reference to pointer:

`void generator(Object*&)`

and I call it as:

```
Object* obj = nullptr;
generator(obj);

...
use obj
...
delete obj;
```

As you can see the user is responsible for the destruction of `obj`. Is there a better way to use smart pointers or other solution to avoid to manual memory management?

I cannot change the `generator` function.

Comment: Just write a wrapper around `generator`. Call it `generator()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you can't modify `generator` :(, you can still use smart pointer:

```
Object* obj = nullptr;
generator(obj);
std::unique_ptr<Object> raii_obj(obj);
...
use obj/raii_obj
...
// auto delete raii_obj.
```

And you can even wrap it in a function:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> make_object()
{
    Object* obj = nullptr;
    generator(obj);
    return std::unique_ptr<Object>(obj);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same without declaring the raw pointer and using directly the smart pointer with the function?

Comment: No, you can't modify internal pointer of `std::unique_ptr` directly.